# Converting an Integer[] to List<integer> automatically in JOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm using PostgreSQL. One of my table fields is an array:

```
"day_of_month" int[] DEFAULT NULL
```

But my domain object for this table is `List<Integer>`. I want to annotate my domain object with `@Column(name = "day_of_month")` so I can use `fetchOneInto(MyDomainType.class)`. The problem is JOOQ converts `int[]` field as `Integer[]` so I have to fetch result, convert `Integer[]` to `List<Integer>` and fill my domain object manually. Is there any automatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the type rewriting system of jOOQ-codegen is not very sophisticated, meaning that "special" data types like arrays or user-defined types are a bit hard to rewrite.

There is a pending feature request [#3310](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3310) to rectify this, but it won't be before jOOQ 3.5. In the mean time, I'm afraid that you:

- Either convert these types yourself:
- Post-process the generated jOOQ meta data to patch such `Field` definitions
- Apply [Taeir's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23993419/521799) and implement a [`RecordMapperProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/). This will not modify the array values in jOOQ records, but at least you will be able to map arrays to `List` when mapping to your `MyDomainType`.

---

Update: As a matter of fact, I suspect that [#3062](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3062) might sufficiently cover your use-case. Maybe, we give this a higher priority for jOOQ 3.4

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with "Automatic", but you can convert an Integer Array into a List of Integers with `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);`, where array is your Integer array.

The other way is also possible: `Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);`.

EDIT:
It might be possible to have JOOQ do this for you. I haven't worked with it myself, but by looking at the documentation, it seems that it is possible to add a `RecordMapper` to a `RecordMapperProvider`. With one of these mappers, you can define how certain db types should be converted to java types (I think at least). This is, however, probably a lot more work than just having a small call to `Arrays.asList()`.

Comment: I want JOOQ to do `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array)` for me so I don't fill domain object myself.